# Postgres INSERT INTO where clause with Java preparedstatement

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement, where-clause

I am trying to insert data in a table with a PreparedStatement in Java and postgres JDBC.
I want to insert into column startdate and column enddate values with a condition that roomnumber is given (?);

PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(
"INSERT INTO room(startdate,enddate) values(?,?) WHERE roomnumber = ?"))

It gives me an error at WHERE.
What is the correct syntax.
Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use UPDATE to change existing rows, INSERT to create new rows.
There are a number of examples in the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html

E.g.: `UPDATE room SET startdate = ?, enddate = ? WHERE roomnumber = ?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
insert into room(startdate, enddate) select '2020-01-01'::date, '2020-02-11'::date where (select roomnumber = ? from roomnumber_table);
```

Also check out this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Insert Into Select and Not Insert Into Values

```
INSERT INTO table1(firstname, lastname)
    select 'Sally', 'Brown'
    Where exists (Select 1 from table2 where field1=val1 )
```